# Oracle multi-column index: determine the most recent couple (year, semester)

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Please suppose you have a multi-column index in an Oracle table:

```
CREATE INDEX MY_USER.MY_INDEX ON MY_USER.MY_TABLE
(YEAR, SEMESTER);
```

The column YEAR is NUMBER(4).
The column SEMESTER is NUMBER(1).

What is the most efficient way to determine the most recent couple (YEAR, SEMESTER)?

I think something like this:

```
select max(YEAR) into MY_YEAR from MY_TABLE;

select max(SEMESTER) from MY_TABLE where YEAR = MY_YEAR;
```

Any other clues?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

EDIT: The table has over 50 million records.

SECOND EDIT: I am using this Oracle version:

```
BANNER
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Productio
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

Comment: Those are two completely different queries.  Please show example input data and expected output.

Comment: I don't believe those are two completely different queries. The first query calculates the max(YEAR) in MY_TABLE.  The second query determines the max(SEMESTER) in MY_TABLE, assuming that YEAR = MAX(YEAR) just determined.

Comment: `select year, semester
from (
  select year,semester, rownm as rn
  from my_table
  order by year desc, semester desc
)
where rn = 1;`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: it hangs up because year and semester are always the same in the entire table..... for now!!

Comment: If they are always the same then why do you need to find the max at all? Just take any row. And if all values are the same, and index won't help at all.

Comment: For NOW, they are always the same.  This is the first block composed by 50 million records.  The second block will be composed of abother other 50 million records, with a different couple (YEAR, SEMESTER).

Comment: As long as you don't have the real data there is no point in tuning the query if all values are going to be the same. Still: my query should only use an index scan, not a table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `semester` can be only `1` or `2`, this could be efficient:

```
with t as
   (select max(year), 1 as semester
   from MY_TABLE
   where semester = 1
   union all
   select max(year), 2 as semester
   from MY_TABLE
   where semester = 2)
select MAX(TO_CHAR(YEAR) || TO_CHAR(SEMESTER)) 
from t;
```

Of course, this is not a generic solution but it should work in your case.

**Update:**

Another idea is this one:

```
SELECT year, semester
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY year, semester 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

The [row_limiting_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA) was introduced in Oracle 12.1

Comment: I am using Oracle 10G (I've just edited my question adding also this information).

Answer (score 1):

Question: What is the most efficient way to determine the more recent couple (YEAR, SEMESTER)?

If this is a one off query that will not need to be optimized how about

Select MAX(TO_CHAR(YEAR) || TO_CHAR(SEMESTER))
FROM MY_TABLE;

Not an elegant solution but it works.

Comment: TABLE ACCESS FULL with your solution.  It hangs up.  MY_TABLE has over 50 million records.

Comment: Just added with an EDIT row.

Answer (score 1):

What if we take Kevinsky's solution, and add a field which is a concatenation of both fields. We can then add an index on the field?

For example:

```
alter table MY_TABLE add (concatenated as TO_CHAR(YEAR) || TO_CHAR(SEMESTER))
CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE(concatenated)
```

Comment: We could create a function based index instead of adding a new column, but I would avoid this.